# Javascript List: Delete and Edit items function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a Javascript To Do list (checklist, without jQuery), which I have already completed, but I cannot figure out how to make an edit and delete button also appear with each of the items the are entered. [This is what I ave so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAwDl.png)

```
    <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ToDoList.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1> To Do List</h1>

        <input type="text" id="inItemText"><button id = "btnAdd">Add</button>

        <div class="tasks-parent">
      <h4>Tasks:</h4>
        <ul id = "todolist">
        </ul>
        </div>
        <script src ="ToDoList.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>

        #btnAdd {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background: #22B473;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        width: auto;
        }

        .tasks-parent{
            border: 2px solid #777;
            margin-top: 5px;
            width: 16.2%;
        }


        html{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        ul{
            width: 400px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        li{
         padding: 5px 10px;
         color: #000;

        }

        li span {
        padding-left: 10px;
        }

        function updateItemStatus(){
            var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
            var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);

            if(this.checked){
            itemText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            } 
            else{
            itemText.style.textDecoration = "none";
            }

        }



        function addNewItem(list, itemText) {

            totalItems++

            var date = new Date();
            var id = "" + date.getMinutes(); + date.getSeconds() +                                                date.getMilliseconds() + "";

        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.id = "li_" + id;

        var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
        checkBox.type = "checkbox";
        checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
        checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus;

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
        span.innerHTML = itemText;

        var edit = document.createElement("a");
        edit.href = "#";
        edit.innerHTML = " edit |";

        var deleteBtn = document.createElement("a");
        deleteBtn.href = "#";
        deleteBtn.innerHTML = " delete";


        listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
        listItem.appendChild(span);
        listItem.appendChild(edit);
        listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

        list.appendChild(listItem);
    }


    var totalItems = 0;

    var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
    inItemText.focus();

    var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
    btnNew.onclick = function(){
        var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");

        var itemText = inItemText.value;
        if(!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " "){
    return false;
        }

        addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
    };

    inItemText.onkeyup = function(event) {

        if(event.which == 13){
        var itemText = inItemText.value;

        if(!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " "){
            return false;
        }

        addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);

        inItemText.focus();
        inItemText.select();
    }

    };

    deleteBtn.onclick = function removeItem() {
     var elem = document.getElementById("item_");
     elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this block of code inside *addNewItem function*. What this does is it binds the onclick event to every list. Here *this* key refers to deleteBtn that was clicked.

```
deleteBtn.onclick = function removeItem() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
```

Check out http://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: To Do List User can edit and delete with each of the items they are entered. Using pure JavaScript.

Check below updated code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>

    <style>
        #btnAdd {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background: #22B473;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 3px 10px;
            width: auto;
        }
        
        .tasks-parent {
            border: 2px solid #777;
            margin-top: 5px;
            width: auto;
        }
        
        html {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        
        ul {
            width: 400px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        li {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            color: #000;
        }
        
        li span {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> To Do List</h1>

    <input type="text" id="inItemText"><button id="btnAdd">ADD</button>

    <div class="tasks-parent">
        <h4>Tasks:</h4>
        <ul id="todolist">
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script>
        function updateItemStatus() {
            var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
            var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);

            if (this.checked) {
                itemText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            } else {
                itemText.style.textDecoration = "none";
            }

        }



        function addNewItem(list, itemText) {

            totalItems++

            var date = new Date();
            var id = "" + date.getMinutes(); + date.getSeconds() + date.getMilliseconds() + "";

            var listItem = document.createElement("li");
            listItem.id = "li_" + id;

            var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
            checkBox.type = "checkbox";
            checkBox.id = "cb_" + totalItems;
            checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus;

            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
            span.innerHTML = itemText;

            var edit = document.createElement("a");
            edit.href = "#";
            edit.innerHTML = " edit |";
            edit.addEventListener('click', editItem, false);

            var deleteBtn = document.createElement("a");
            deleteBtn.href = "#";
            deleteBtn.innerHTML = " delete";
            deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', removeItem, false);


            listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
            listItem.appendChild(span);
            listItem.appendChild(edit);
            listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

            list.appendChild(listItem);
        }


        var totalItems = 0;
        var lastUpdatedItemId = '';
        var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
        inItemText.focus();

        var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
        btnNew.onclick = function() {
            if (this.innerHTML == 'ADD') {
                var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");

                var itemText = inItemText.value;
                if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
                    return false;
                }

                addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
            } else if (this.innerHTML == 'EDIT') {
                this.innerHTML = 'ADD';
                var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");

                var itemText = inItemText.value;
                if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
                    return false;
                }
                document.getElementById(lastUpdatedItemId).innerHTML = itemText;
               inItemText.value = "";
            }
        }
        inItemText.onkeyup = function(event) {

            if (event.which == 13) {
                var itemText = inItemText.value;

                if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
                    return false;
                }

                addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);

                inItemText.focus();
                inItemText.select();
            }

        };

        function removeItem() {
            var li = this.parentNode;
            li.remove();
        }

        function editItem() {
            btnNew.innerHTML = 'EDIT';
            var li = this.parentNode;
            var item = li.getElementsByTagName("*");
            inItemText.value = item[1].innerHTML;
            lastUpdatedItemId = item[1].id;
            console.log(item);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not much use unless you show them the bit you changed, that way they learn something rather than use SO as a debugging service

Comment: Whats I made wrong in the above snippet.Can you put the comment I will improve answer.

Comment: There's no info about what you fixed just a big dump of fixed code, it doesn't help people learn

Comment: Thank you Toni for your suggestion.

Comment: @mahendra, I learned something from your post, so don't listen to these people.  Also, there's nothing wrong with using SO as a debugging service.  That's the whole point: getting solutions to your coding issues.